# INSERT and OUTPUT

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm executing a very simple SQL statement, which I have below:

```
INSERT INTO pictures OUTPUT Inserted.id DEFAULT VALUES
```

I feel that it should work, but for some reason I can't get this simple error. It prints the following:

> OperationalError: near "OUTPUT": syntax error

I'm using sqlite

Comment: The code works when I try it:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8947cf48eec3915b264de57c6fad881.

Comment: OUTPUT is invalid in SQLite.

Comment: OK, thank you. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: If you call `SELECT last_insert_rowid()` in the **same transaction** you will get the last inserted `rowid`.

Comment: SQLite also has the [returning](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html) clause as of v3.35.0

Comment: For some reason, ```SELECT last_insert_rowid()``` doesn't work. It returns the following: No item with that key -  although I have a column id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT. The RETURNING clause also yields OperationalError: near "RETURNING": syntax error when used like this ```INSERT INTO pictures DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING id```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLITE you need to use last_insert_rowid() function to get the last inserted ID like -

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c070d5fd6a8017071646f1102fd69bd6)